# I cannot run Electron

Tags: electron

I'm trying to develop an Electron application but I am dealing with this frustrating issue. It does not start but has no errors.

**What I have tried so far:**

- Reinstalled Windows 10
- Installed Windows Build Tools
- Installed Python 2.7
- Tried Electron example code

**Additional Information**

- Node version v11.0.0
- Electron version v3.0.6
- Yarn version v1.12.1

What is the problem? I have tried installing via npm and yarn but that didn't work either.

**Code**

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

let mainWindow

function createWindow () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})

  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')

  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    process.stderr.write('Closed')
    mainWindow = null
  })
}

app.on('error', error => {
  process.stderr.write(error)
})

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('ready', function () {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

**Output**

No error output.

I do however see the process in [Task Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHLnG.png) but no window.

Comment: Update your question to include outputs - otherwise we have no idea what the issue is.

Comment: Paste your code into your question as well.

Answer (score 2):

`mainWindow` is not equal to `null` that's why it doesn't run `createWindow()` function. Change this:

```
app.on('ready', function () {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

To:

```
app.on("ready", createWindow);
```

Comment: To clarify, `mainWindow` isn't `null`, but `undefined`, which are different things in JS. Interestingly, `(null == undefined)` is true, but `(null === undefined)` isn't. `undefined` still converts to `false` though, so `if(!mainWindow)` would've worked too.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess. . . but I don't see where you are calling `window.show()`

```
mainWindow.on('ready-to-show', () => {
    mainWindow.show()
})
```

That could go in the "app ready` function.

Comment: Yep, that was the issue. Thank you!

Comment: why is that hidden in the first place?